# .htaccess redirect "domain.tld/" to "domain.tld/home.html"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2, root

I have a website here on my localhost :

```
http://localhost/mysite/www/index.php
```

I have some RewriteRules to redirect like this :

```
http://localhost/mysite/www/index.php?page=home
->  http://localhost/mysite/www/home.html
```

And now, I want to do a redirection like this :

```
http://localhost/mysite/www/
->  http://localhost/mysite/www/home.html
```

---

I have an environment variable named `REWRITE_BASE` containing `/mysite/www/`. So what I thought to do was to compare `{REQUEST_URI}` to `%{ENV:REWRITE_BASE}` ... like this:

```
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} =%{ENV:REWRITE_BASE}

RewriteRule . %{ENV:REWRITE_BASE}home\.html [R=301,L]
```

But it don't works well.

To help you understand what I want to do, here is the working code in PHP to do what I want:

```
$rewriteBase = getenv('REWRITE_BASE');

if ($rewriteBase === $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
    header('Location: '.$rewriteBase.'home.html');
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... so, as I can't use a variable for my comparison, here is the way that I made it works :

```
# Redirect domain.tld/ to domain.tld/home.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/www/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/mysite/www/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}home\.html [R=301,L]

# RewriteBase equivalent - Production environment
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITE_BASE:/www/]

# RewriteBase equivalent - Development environment
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITE_BASE:/mysite/www/,E=DEVELOPMENT_ENV:1]

# Website rewritings
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*))?\.html$ %{ENV:REWRITE_BASE}index\.php?page=$1&view=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Now it's alright. Thanks for your answers! ;)

Comment: Erf, I have another problem with this method. I can't have an index.html like a "website in construction".

I tried to add a "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}index.html !-f" before the first RewriteRule... didn't worked.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do won't work, because `mod_rewrite` doesn't expand any variables present in its test patterns. Therefore, when you do something like this...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =%{ENV:REWRITE_BASE}
```

...What you're actually doing is comparing the value of `%{REQUEST_URI}` to the string `"%{ENV:REWRITE_BASE}"`, instead of the value `"/mysite/www/"` like you wanted. Is there a reason that you can't specify the value directly in your `RewriteCond` or simply move the rules so that they're relative to the `/mysite/www/` directory to begin with?

There might be another way to approach the problem, but unfortunately (and for some good reasons) you cannot perform that kind of comparison using `mod_rewrite`.